# Android test boolean method returns false every time?

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, mocking, mockito

I want to test method `checkTextLength()` of `DesignInputField` that returns boolean value. But it returns false every time. Tried mock library to do this. When I write this code `Mockito.`when`(designInputField.checkTextLength()).thenReturn(true)` it returns true. But I think it's not right way to test this code.

DesignInputField.kt

```
 class DesignInputField @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
        defStyleAttr: Int = 0
    ) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
        private var textLength = 1;
        private var textLengthType = 1;
        }
    
      fun checkTextLength(): Boolean {
            return when (textLengthType) {
                0 -> text.length < textLength
                1 -> text.length > textLength
                2 -> text.length <= textLength
                3 -> text.length >= textLength
                4 -> text.length == textLength
                else -> false
            }
        }
```

DesignInputFieldTest.kt

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class DesignInputFieldTest{
    @Mock
    lateinit var designInputField: DesignInputField
  @Test
    fun `cardNameGreaterThanOne`() {
        Mockito.`when`(designInputField.text).thenReturn("ab")
        Assert.assertEquals(true,designInputField.checkTextLength())
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're mocking `designInputField`, so all its functions are mocked, including `checkTextLength`.

You could resort to instrumented tests, but, in your case, I would suggest extracting the logic for `checkTextLength` into a helper top-level function and test that. E.g.:

```
fun checkTextLength(type: Int, text: String): Boolean {
    return when (type) {
        0 -> text.length < textLength
        1 -> text.length > textLength
        2 -> text.length <= textLength
        3 -> text.length >= textLength
        4 -> text.length == textLength
        else -> false
    }
}
```

Then, in `DesignInputField` you can call it:

```
fun checkTextLength() = checkTextLength(textLengthType, text)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood why I get false everytime. In my case, I am writing these test for an existing project of company which I work. So, I don't change now with Helper using like you say. If you can add instrumanted test code like how we call  `DesignInputField` class and how can test this method it would be so good.:)

Comment: You could try using a [spy](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Spy.html) instead of a mock. With a spy you can mock only the functions you want to mock. However, you need to be able to instantiate `DesignInputField` to spy on it.